# sub _init in Perl explanation

Tags: perl

I was wondering what this subroutine does in Perl. I believe i have the general idea but i'm wondering about some of the syntax.

```
sub _init 
{
  my $self = shift;
  if (@_) {
    my %extra = @_;
    @$self{keys %extra} = values %extra;
  }
}
```

Here is what i think it does: essentially add any "extra" key-value pairs to the nameless hash refereced by the variable $self. Also i'm not 100% sure about this but i think `my $self = shift` is actually referring to the variable `$self` that called the `_init()` subroutine.

My specific questions are:

1. Is $self actually referring to the variable that called the subroutine `_init()` ?
2. What does the `@$` syntax mean when writing `@$self{keys %extra} = values %extra;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your understanding is correct. This allows the user of a class to set any parameters they want into the object.

1. Yes. If you call, for example, `$myobject->_init('color', 'green')`, then this code will set `$myobject->{'color'} = 'green'`.
2. This is a somewhat confusing hash operation. `keys %extra` is a list (obviously of keys). We are effectively using a "hash slice" here. Think of it like an array slice, where you can call `@$arrayref[1, 3, 4]`. We use the `@` sign here because we're talking about a list - it's the list of values corresponding to the list of keys `keys %extra` in the hash referenced by `$self`.

Another way to write this would be:

```
foreach my $key (keys %extra) {
  $self->{$key} = $extra{$key};
}
```

Comment: Thanks amon, obviously wasn't thinking there

Answer (score 4):

> Is `$self` actually referring to the variable that called the subroutine `_init()`?

Variables don't call subroutines.

The invocant (what's on the left of the `->` in `->_init()`) is passed to the method as its first argument, and you placed this in `$self`. (`shift()` is short for `shift(@_)` in subs.)

> What does the `@$` syntax mean when writing `@$self{keys %extra} = values %extra;`

`@hash{LIST}` is a [hash slice](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html).

`@{ EXPR }{LIST}` is a hash slice where the hash to slice is specified through a reference. The curlies are optional when `EXPR` is simple scalar lookup, so `@{ $hash_ref }{LIST}` can be written as `@$hash_ref{LIST}`.

The method add the arguments to `%$self`, the hash-based object used as the invocant. It could also have been written as follows:

```
%$self = ( %$self, @_ );
```